# Assume $ \lim_{k \to \infty }x_{k}=x_{0}$ and $ \lim_{k \to \infty }y_{k}=y_{0}$.

Tags: analysis

Assume $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }x_{k}=x_{0}$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }y_{k}=y_{0}$.

Prove that, if there is a $k_{1}$ such that $x_{k}\leq y_{k}$ for all $k\geq k_{1}$, then $x_{0}\leq y_{0}$.

I proved that :

if $x_{k}\leq y_{k}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then $x_{0}\leq y_{0}$.

How should I prove the original problem by using this?

Comment: Apply what you have proved to the sequences $\{x_{k_1},x_{k_1+1},x_{k_1+2},...\}$ and  $\{y_{k_1},y_{k_1+1},y_{k_1+2},...\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nature of a sequence doesn't depends on finitely many terms. You can start from $k_1$ - th term and apply what you already know.

But, let me allow to write the complete proof.

$\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }x_{k}=x_{0}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }y_{k}=y_{0}$

$\exists k_1 $ such that $x_k\le y_k$  for all $ k\ge k_1$

Claim: $x_{0}\leq y_{0}$

We argue by contradiction.

Suppose, $x_{0}> y_{0}$

Then, $(x_k -y_k) _{k\in \Bbb{N}}\to ( x_{0} -y_{0})>0$

> Lemma : $(x_k)\to x$ and $x>0$ then $\exists k_1\in \Bbb{N}$ such that
> $x_k > \frac{x}{2}$ for all $k\ge k_1$.
>
> Proof :
>
> Hint : Choose, $\epsilon =\frac{x}{2}>0$

Using the above lemma, $\exists k_1\in\Bbb{N}$ such that

$$x_k-y_k>\frac{x_{0}-y_{0}}{2}>0 \space ,\forall k\ge k_1$$

In other words, $x_k>y_k \space ,\forall k\ge k_1$

This contradict our hypothesis that
$x_k\le y_k$  for all but finitely many $k$'s.

Hence, $x_0\le y_0$ .

Note:

$x_0=  y_0$ may hold even when $x_k <y_k$.

Ex : $0<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in {\Bbb{N}}$

$0=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{1}{n}}$